# What's the best algorithm to group the same string together?

Tags: algorithm

Each sort algorithm will be the job, but it's a OVERKILL.

For input like:

```
aa
cc
aa
bb
dd
bb
cc
```

I just need something like:

```
aa
aa
cc
cc
bb
bb
dd
```

The order of each pattern is not required.

Is there such an algorithm for this kind of job?

Comment: Wouldn't creating a dictionary with the key being the word and the value the count suffice? You could just pass through your list, add the key with 1 count if it's not there and update the key otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply want to use a [hashtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable) here, or more abstractly an [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). Iterate over the input, adding it to the hashtable with value (tag, if you prefer) of *1* if it hasn't yet been seen, or incrementing the count by one if it already exists in the hashtable.

The algorithm is thus *O(n)* in both time and space, which is as good as you could reasonably expect. I recommend some reading up on hashtables, as it is a highly useful data structure that appears in all sorts of places in algorithm and software design.

Comment: More detailed and implementation-level than mine -- I approve. +1

Comment: @BlackVegetable: Ah thank you. I didn't see yours when you posted, but we seem to have just explained the same solution in different ways. :) +1 in any case.

Answer (score 2):

Well, off of the top of my head you could run a pass that counts how many of each element exist and then create a new array with them posted in order.  That would be O(n) but is not "in-place".

Thus:

```
// Make outputArrayCounter
// While inputArray has elements left:
//   if current element is new, add to outputArrayCounter
//   if current element has been seen before, increment a counter associated with that 
//   element.
// Part 2...
// Make outputArray
// create the appropriate number of elements as found in the outputArrayCounter for
// every different element type.
```

Let's try an example:

We have an original input of `aa bb aa cc cc dd cc`.

We will make our counter device, and scan the input.  `aa`, the first element is read and as we have never encountered an `aa` before, we will add this to our counter device.

Counter device: `[(aa, 1)]`

Now let's continue by reading the next input, `bb`.  It is also not found and is added:

Counter device: `[(aa, 1), (bb, 1)]`

Step again and read `aa` as the third element.  This is found in our device, and so instead of adding it again, we increment the counter associated with `aa` by 1.

Counter device: `[(aa, 2), (bb, 1)]`

I will continue and give you the end counter device state:

`[(aa, 2), (bb, 1), (cc, 3), (dd, 1)]`

Now we go through the device and print out the number of each element that many times, with each element of the same *name* together. (if order matters, that is an implementation detail that will determine whether to use an associated set-dictionary, or some kind of duple-array device that stores ordering.  That is language specific but I'm sure you can figure that out.  If you cannot, comment here and I will describe a solution.)

`print aa aa bb cc cc cc dd`