# Why map reduce sort the keys instead of simply grouping the same keys together?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

IMO Hadoop can save CPU and memory if it simply groups the same key together

(as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14329793/807893),it's `O(n)`),

instead of strictly sorting the keys(which is `O(nlgn)`).

Is there any application that depends on that the keys are strictly sorted?

Comment: Temporal analysis, pattern of life, certain reduce-side join methods, ..

Answer (score 1):

You're right, a Map/Reduce job doesn't necessarily need to have the keys sorted, Hadoop does this mainly because that's what it uses for grouping, because it's convenient, not because it's necessary, which can result in unnecessary overhead if your application doesn't depend on ordering.

It's actually being debated on [the MAPREDUCE Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1639), I would advise reading all the comments there for more implementation details.

Interesting anecdote, [the MARS project](http://www.cse.ust.hk/catalac/papers/mars_pact08.pdf) reported a 45% boost using hashing instead of sorting using their own implementation.